# Layering of protocols in twisted

Tags: python, protocols, twisted

I've almost got it -- but I'm missing key points.....

I'm trying to figure out how one might built "layered" protocol stacks in Twisted.    I can understand how one attached a single protocol and handles events with Defers, but with if I want the traditional OSI layers model?   Assume I have a line-oriented protocol at the bottom on a TCP connector, and I want multiple line-oriented protocols stacked on top until I get to application space.

(Think of me wanted to implement the TCP/IP stack itself in twisted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OSI layering model is *mostly* irrelevant to Twisted (and, I would posit, mostly irrelevant to software in general).  Looking at each layer at a time:

1. physical: obviously, Twisted is not an ethernet cable or a physical switch, so it can't do this.
2. data link: in order for Twisted to run over a network interface, your operating system needs to be connected to a physical network. data-link protocols typically need to be implemented in hard real-time equipment, often in hardware, so Twisted isn't suitable for that.
3. network: this layer, if it's distinct from the "transport" layer, then it's stuff like BGP and routers and whatnot which is happening distinct from your application.
4. transport: At this layer, we have two interfaces, [`IProtocol`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IProtocol.html) and [`ITransport`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.ITransport.html).  The transport delivers bytes *from* the transport to an `IProtocol` via `dataReceived`, and the application delivers bytes *to* the transport via `ITransport.write()`.  (This relationship is then inverted on the other end of the wire.)
5. session: (this is implicitly part of the transport)
6. presentation: this is like, CSS stylesheets or something
7. application: obviously Twisted doesn't do this part, you do it yourself.

In-protocol layering, however, is somewhat more ad-hoc.  The usual idiom right now is to simply subclass Protocol and then delegate from `dataReceived` to a new method, specific to your layering idiom, such as `lineReceived`, then have the next layer up subclass that.

If you actually want a TCP implementation that uses Twisted, [look here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~divmod-dev/divmod.org/trunk/view/head:/Vertex/vertex/ptcp.py).

If you want to see a proposal for interfaces that will improve layering within Twisted itself, [see here](http://tm.tl/1956) instead.

Comment: I don't think the formal, documented, widely used protocol and transport interfaces are best described as "ad-hoc", no matter how much you love tubes. :)

Comment: The relationship between `dataReceived` → `stringReceived` or `dataReceived` → `lineReceived` *is* ad-hoc, though.

Comment: OK, updated the answer to describe the non-ad-hoc interfaces for protocol/transport layering.